# ajax cors unknown errors

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome, cors

I am trying to solve the problem of cross-domain, whenever I change my code, it never works and I think there must be something wrong with my ajax code, please check in the code, and give me some advice, thank you.

```js
function login(url,name,password){
 console.log("login");
 console.log(url);
 var tips = document.getElementById('tips');
 $.ajax({
         url: url,
   type:"POST",
         headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
         data:{
    "user_code" : name,
    "user_key" : password
   },
   dataType: "json",
      // xhrFields: {
      //     withCredentials: true
      // },
   success:function(data){
    if(data.token == undefined){
     console.log(data);
     tips.innerHTML = "错误";
    }else{
     saveToken('token',data.token,1);
                 saveToken('user_id',data.user_id,1);
                 checkToken(data.token);
    }
         },
         error: function(msg){
          console.log(msg);
          console.log("fail");
         }
 });
}
```

Comment: Changing **your** clientside code doesn't help at all, if the server doesn't support CORS and send the appropriate headers.

Comment: CORS is done by your server side, could you please explain about your server code

Comment: don't forget, with `"Content-Type": "application/json"` a `POST` will trigger an `OPTIONS` preflight request

Comment: Anup's answer `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` will likely resolve your problem.

However, it is possible to start chrome with no security and then retest your code.  If it is a CORS or other security violation, your code will start working, and you can resume troubleshooting knowing the problem isn't in your code. 

Create a shortcut for chrome, then edit the properties, and put something like this: 

`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --user-data-dir="C:/devChrome" --disable-web-security` 

for the target.

Only use this to test your own code.

Comment: i asked a friend of mine to run my code, it turned out that something went wrong with the json format, changed the code : data:{ "user_code" : name, "user_key" : password } to: data:JSON.stringify({ "user_code" : name, "user_key" : password }) and it worked. thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

Append in server response in header field,Below code helps you for resolving the issue,i am using below code in java.You can use any other language also.

```
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type,X-Requested-With,accept,Origin");
```